# TeXLive failing to install from .iso

Tags: texlive, offline

I need to perform an offline installation of TeXLive on Windows 10. I've downloaded the .iso file from CTAN, specifically from [this directory](https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/systems/texlive/Images/), I've mounted the image with the windows native tool and double clicked `install-windows-tl.bat`, it shows the message:

```
Installing to: C:/texlive/2022
Installing [1/6, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: hyphen-base [22k]
xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
TLPDB::_install_data: Decompressing C:\Users\kojar\AppData\Local\Temp\K6kwQOVH7U\JmXZjgdB2X/hyphen-base.r62751.tar.xz failed for F:/archive/hyphen-base.r62751.tar.xz
TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install hyphen-base
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2000, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2001, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2002, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2003, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2011, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2011, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2011, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2011, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2011, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2011, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2011, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2012, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2006, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2010, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2010, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2010, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2010, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2010, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2009, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2009, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2009, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2009, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2009, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2009, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2009, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2009, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2009, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2009, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2009, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2009, <STDIN> line 194.
print() on closed filehandle PROFILE at F://install-tl line 2009, <STDIN> line 194.
Installation failed.
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
F://install-tl: Could not write to install-tl.log, so flushing messages to stderr.
TeX Live installer invocation: F://install-tl -from_ext_gui 
Loading F://tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
Installing TeX Live 2022 from: F:/ (not verified)
Platform: win32 => 'Windows'
Distribution: inst (compressed)
Directory for temporary files: C:\Users\kojar\AppData\Local\Temp\K6kwQOVH7U
Installer revision: 62745
Database revision: 62880
Settings:
  TEXDIR: "C:/texlive/2022"
  TEXMFCONFIG: "~/.texlive2022/texmf-config"
  TEXMFHOME: "~/texmf"
  TEXMFLOCAL: "C:/texlive/texmf-local"
  TEXMFSYSCONFIG: "C:/texlive/2022/texmf-config"
  TEXMFSYSVAR: "C:/texlive/2022/texmf-var"
  TEXMFVAR: "~/.texlive2022/texmf-var"
  binary_amd64-freebsd: ""
  binary_universal-darwin: ""
  binary_win32: "1"
  binary_x86_64-cygwin: ""
  binary_x86_64-darwinlegacy: ""
  binary_x86_64-linux: ""
  collection-basic: "1"
  collection-bibtexextra: "1"
  collection-binextra: "1"
  collection-context: "1"
  collection-fontsextra: "1"
  collection-fontsrecommended: "1"
  collection-fontutils: "1"
  collection-formatsextra: "1"
  collection-games: "1"
  collection-humanities: "1"
  collection-langarabic: "1"
  collection-langchinese: "1"
  collection-langcjk: "1"
  collection-langcyrillic: "1"
  collection-langczechslovak: "1"
  collection-langenglish: "1"
  collection-langeuropean: "1"
  collection-langfrench: "1"
  collection-langgerman: "1"
  collection-langgreek: "1"
  collection-langitalian: "1"
  collection-langjapanese: "1"
  collection-langkorean: "1"
  collection-langother: "1"
  collection-langpolish: "1"
  collection-langportuguese: "1"
  collection-langspanish: "1"
  collection-latex: "1"
  collection-latexextra: "1"
  collection-latexrecommended: "1"
  collection-luatex: "1"
  collection-mathscience: "1"
  collection-metapost: "1"
  collection-music: "1"
  collection-pictures: "1"
  collection-plaingeneric: "1"
  collection-pstricks: "1"
  collection-publishers: "1"
  collection-texworks: ""
  collection-wintools: "1"
  collection-xetex: "1"
  doc_splitting_supported: "1"
  free_size: "-1"
  inst_platform: "win32"
  instopt_adjustpath: "1"
  instopt_adjustrepo: "1"
  instopt_letter: ""
  instopt_portable: ""
  instopt_write18_restricted: "1"
  n_collections_available: "41"
  n_collections_selected: "40"
  n_systems_available: "6"
  n_systems_selected: "1"
  scheme-basic: ""
  scheme-context: ""
  scheme-custom: ""
  scheme-full: "1"
  scheme-gust: ""
  scheme-infraonly: ""
  scheme-medium: ""
  scheme-minimal: ""
  scheme-small: ""
  scheme-tetex: ""
  selected_scheme: "scheme-custom"
  src_splitting_supported: "1"
  this_platform: "win32"
  tlpdbopt_autobackup: "1"
  tlpdbopt_backupdir: "tlpkg/backups"
  tlpdbopt_create_formats: "1"
  tlpdbopt_desktop_integration: "1"
  tlpdbopt_file_assocs: "1"
  tlpdbopt_generate_updmap: ""
  tlpdbopt_install_docfiles: "1"
  tlpdbopt_install_srcfiles: "1"
  tlpdbopt_location: "F:/"
  tlpdbopt_post_code: "1"
  tlpdbopt_sys_bin: "/usr/local/bin"
  tlpdbopt_sys_info: "/usr/local/share/info"
  tlpdbopt_sys_man: "/usr/local/share/man"
  tlpdbopt_w32_multi_user: ""
  total_size: "7402"
Installing to: C:/texlive/2022
Not an admin install; not making read-only
Not an admin install; not making read-only
Not an admin install; not making read-only
Not an admin install; not making read-only
Installing [1/6, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: hyphen-base [22k]
TLPDB::_install_data: Decompressing C:\Users\kojar\AppData\Local\Temp\K6kwQOVH7U\JmXZjgdB2X/hyphen-base.r62751.tar.xz failed for F:/archive/hyphen-base.r62751.tar.xz
TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install hyphen-base
Installation failed.
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
```

Fair enough, I'll install with admin permissions, but then I get the following log:

```
Installing to: C:/texlive/2022
Installing [1/6, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: hyphen-base [22k]
xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
TLPDB::_install_data: Decompressing C:\Users\kojar\AppData\Local\Temp\Sw5JSBZqv0\DlgHbgeYyV/hyphen-base.r62751.tar.xz failed for F:/archive/hyphen-base.r62751.tar.xz
TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install hyphen-base
Installation failed.
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
Or you can restart by running the installer with:
  install-tl-windows.bat --profile installation.profile [YOUR-EXTRA-ARGS]
F://install-tl: Writing log in current directory: C:/WINDOWS/system32/install-tl.log
```

I'd like for it not to require administrator privileges if that's possible.

Anyway, what is going on here? Can I use some older iso from somewhere? I've checked the MD5 hashes and they've matched.

Comment: the message you show says "Compressed data is corrupt" ie you downloaded a bad copy, reading it with admin permissions is not going to fix that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle noticed that, but din't think it could be broken on the server, as I've checked the md5sum.

Comment: I dont know, as you say md5 probably means you have the right file. Perhaps it  is an issue with the windows iso mount. Can you look at the referenced file and check by hand with tar if that file looks OK?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've tried to do the same with an iso from 2021, got the same error in a different file. I can navigate to the file location and open the file with 7zip, but there doesn't seem to be any hash file I could use to check that tar.